# What should be max sstable count to improve read latency on prod cluster?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

We are facing read latancy issue on our prod cassandra cluster. I am suspecting that sstables are the reasons. Can any one tell that what should be max sstable count on cassandra node? or any other reasons for read latency? acssandra version 2.0.11.

Comment: depends, whats your compaction strategy? whats your schema?

Comment: STCS compaction strategy and what does it mean by schema?

Comment: your create table statement. Depending on schema STCS can start to have read latency impacts at around 30-ish sstables. However the min and max partition and clustering keys are kept in the meta data so things like time series with the clustering key as the time will auto exclude older sstables and not have same impact. If your trying to improve read latencies just try changing it on one node to LeveledCompactionStrategy which is almost always better anyway.

Comment: But changing compaction strategy seems not good idea because data size around 1tb on each node. Is there any other way forward?

Comment: its safe to change compaction strategies, especially the STCS <-> LCS change. It will just take awhile for it rebuild everything. Within L0 of LCS its STCS anyway so initially theres not much difference except that the extra compactions that will be running. Doing it 1 table at a time should be good. You can use JMX to change it just 1 node at a time if want to test out its impact. https://support.datastax.com/hc/en-us/articles/213370546-Change-CompactionStrategy-and-sub-properties-via-JMX

Comment: Yes, we can but I am little afraid because already cluster stressed high load due to data size and other reasons. Thanks for your support.